# NLTK sentence_bleu method 7 gives scores above 1

Tags: nltk, bleu

When using the NLTK `sentence_bleu` function in combination with `SmoothingFunction` method 7, the max score is `1.1167470964180197`. This while the BLEU score is defined to be between `0` and `1`.

This score shows up for perfect matches with the reference. I'm using method 7 since I do not always have sentences of length 4, some may be lower. Using method 5 gives the same result. Other methods do give 1.0 as a perfect score.

It occurs when I use a single reference and candidate, for example:

```
from nltk.translate.bleu_score import sentence_bleu, SmoothingFunction
cc = SmoothingFunction()
reference = ['overofficious 98461 54363 39016 78223 52180']
candidate = 'overofficious 98461 54363 39016 78223 52180'
sentence_bleu(reference, candidate, smoothing_function=cc.method7)
```

This gives the score: `1.1167470964180197`

Am I doing something wrong, is this expected behavior or is there a bug in the implementation of the smoothing function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this implementation is at least consistent with Chen and Cherry, 2014. They suggested to average `n-1, n, n+1` -gram counts. The also defined `m0_prime` as `m1 + 1` (so in our case it will be 2 and that breaks our computations).

I'm using `method5` (it's used by `method7`) from [here](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/translate/bleu_score.html).

```
cc = SmoothingFunction()
references = ['overofficious 98461 54363 39016 78223 52180'.split()]
candidate = 'overofficious 98461 54363 39016 78223 52180'.split()
p_n = [Fraction(1, 1)] * 4
p_n5 = cc.method5(p_n, references, candidate, len(candidate))
```

Output:

```
[Fraction(4, 3), Fraction(10, 9), Fraction(28, 27), Fraction(82, 81)]
```

We may compute `4/3` like this: `(2 + 1 + 1) / 3`; `10/9 = (4/3 + 1 + 1) / 3` and so on.